# mongoose Schema issue while populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js13

I am facing an issue in next 13.3, Everything looks fine in the development server, but in production,, I got an error called..

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Categories."

If I click on a category that leads me to the category detail page and then come back to Home Page,, all errors will be gone,, and the Application start working Perfectly fine as expected.

Now Above Error,, I have mentioned is not the issue I guess checkout the code below as I have defined both possible ways if exist go with it else create it here is my code

**Category Schema**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    categoryName : String,
    categoryDescription :String ,
    categoryImage : String ,
    categorySlug : String

},{timestamps : true});

const Category = mongoose.models.Categories || mongoose.model('Categories', CategorySchema);

export default Category;
```

**Product Schema**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";



const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productName : String,
    productDescription :String ,
    productImage : String ,
    productSlug : String,
    productPrice : Number,
    productQuantity : Number,
    productFeatured : Boolean,
    productCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Categories',
        required: true
    },

},{timestamps : true});

const Product = mongoose.models.Products  || mongoose.model('Products', ProductSchema);

export default Product;
```

Everything look fine still I am facing this issue , I have no Idea what should i do to fix this

I have Tried using singular Form like **Product** **Categroy** for the schema as its automatically become plural

Checkout Application at
https://nextjs-ecommerce-typescript.vercel.app/

checkout Application Code At
https://github.com/Abdullah-moiz/nextjs-ecommerce

Any future Explanation Required Please Let me know !